# adding infowindow to google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to add some infowindow content to my markers on a google map.  I can query my server, get some data, put the markers on the map.  That works.  What doesn't work is that nothing happens when I click on the marker.  I would think that the infowindow would popup.  Unfortunately, it has been so long since I have done google maps programming, I am effectively starting over.  For some reason, the marker's click event is not being called.  Any suggestions regarding my dumbness are appreciated.  TIA

```
<script>
    var map, geocoder;
    var Markers = [];
    function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: { lat: 0.0, lng: 0.0 },
            zoom: 12
        });
        if (!Modernizr.geolocation) {
            alert("Your browser sucks. Get a new one, maybe one that is up to date and supports GPS.")
            return;
        }
        else {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(show_map);
        }
    }
    function show_map(position) {
        map.setZoom(12);
        var Latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        var Longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        map.setCenter({ lat: Latitude, lng: Longitude });
        var bounds = map.getBounds();
        var url = "/api/xxxxxxxxjsonendpoint";
        var lowerLeft = bounds.getSouthWest();
        var upperRight = bounds.getNorthEast();
        var lat0 = lowerLeft.lat();
        var lng0 = lowerLeft.lng();
        var lat1 = upperRight.lat();
        var lng1 = upperRight.lng();
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var data = { LowerLeftLat: lat0, LowerLeftLng: lng0, UpperRightLat: lat1, UpperRightLng: lng1 };
        $.get(url, data, function (result) {
            for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                var address = result[i].Address1 + " " + (result[i].Address2 != null ? result[i].Address2 : "") + " " + result[i].City + " " + result[i].Province + " " + result[i].PostalCode + " " + result[i].Country;
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: geocodeAddress(geocoder, map, address),
                    map: map,
                    title: address
                });
                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: i
                });
                makeInfoWindowEvent(map, infowindow, "test" + i, marker);
            }
        });
    }
    function geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap, address) {
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
            if (status === 'OK') {
                resultsMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: resultsMap,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location
                });
            } else {
                alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
            }
        });
    }
    function makeInfoWindowEvent(map, infowindow, contentString, marker) {
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
            infowindow.setContent(contentString);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    }
</script>
```

---

Here is the most recent update of my code.  Still no worky........

```
<script>
    var map, geocoder;
    var Markers = [];
    var infowindow;
    function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: { lat: 0.0, lng: 0.0 },
            zoom: 12
        });
        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        if (!Modernizr.geolocation) {
            alert("Your browser sucks. Get a new one, maybe one that is up to date and supports GPS.")
            return;
        }
        else {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(show_map);
        }
    }
    function show_map(position) {
        map.setZoom(12);
        var Latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        var Longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        map.setCenter({ lat: Latitude, lng: Longitude });
        var bounds = map.getBounds();
        var url = "/api/xxxxxxx/yyyyyyyyyy";
        var lowerLeft = bounds.getSouthWest();
        var upperRight = bounds.getNorthEast();
        var lat0 = lowerLeft.lat();
        var lng0 = lowerLeft.lng();
        var lat1 = upperRight.lat();
        var lng1 = upperRight.lng();
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var data = { LowerLeftLat: lat0, LowerLeftLng: lng0, UpperRightLat: lat1, UpperRightLng: lng1 };
        $.get(url, data, function (result) {
            for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                var address = result[i].Address1 + " " +
                    (result[i].Address2 != null ? result[i].Address2 : "") +
                    " " + result[i].City + " " + result[i].Province + " " +
                    result[i].PostalCode + " " + result[i].Country;
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: geocodeAddress(geocoder, map, address),
                    map: map,
                    title: address,
                    content: address
                });

                makeInfoWindowEvent(infowindow, "test" + i, marker);
            }
        });
    }
    function geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap, address) {
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
            if (status === 'OK') {
                resultsMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: resultsMap,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location
                });
            } else {
                alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
            }
        });
    }
    function makeInfoWindowEvent(infowindow, contentString, marker) {
        (function (zinfowindow, zcontentString, zmarker) {
            zinfowindow.setContent(zcontentString);
            google.maps.event.addListener(zmarker, 'click', function () {
                zinfowindow.open(map, zmarker);
            });
        })(infowindow, contentString, marker);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: `position: geocodeAddress(geocoder, map, address)`  the `geocodeAddress` function doesn't (and can't because it is asynchronous) return anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
function makeInfoWindowEvent(map, infowindow, contentString, marker) {
    infowindow.setContent(contentString);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code crash because when the listener is calling, the value of `marker` and `infowindow` have already changed. You can try something like this (just change the `makeInfoWindowEvent` function):

```
function makeInfoWindowEvent(map, infowindow, contentString, marker) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        infowindow.setContent(contentString);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
        console.log (contentString);
        console.log (marker);
    });
}
```

Normally, the output will be always the same for `contentString` and `marker`.

In order to pass the real value of the `marker`, `contentString` and `infowindow`, you have to create an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Glossaire/IIFE). Like this, the value of the variables will be copy inside the function:

```
function makeInfoWindowEvent(map, infowindow, contentString, marker) {
    (function (zinfowindow, zcontentString, zmarker) {
       zinfowindow.setContent(zcontentString);
       google.maps.event.addListener(zmarker, 'click', function () {
         zinfowindow.open(map, zmarker);
       });
    })(infowindow, contentString, marker);
}
```

However, you do not need to pass map as parameter because the value of map is always the same.

*Tell me if you have some questions.*

Comment: Thanks for your code.  Unfortunately, it is not working.

Comment: Here is the code I am using.  I am not seeing any errors that are popping up.  I have updated my code in the question with the code that I am currently trying.

PS. I am dealing with health issues in both of my parents, so it may take me a while to respond to any questions/comments.
 
TIA

Comment: Here is a video of what I am getting when I debug.  [link](https://www.screencast.com/t/2Q3mNjP3IK)

Comment: I've got the code working now.  This was incredibly helpful.  :-)

Comment: Basically, I wasn't paying enough attention.  The marker was also being created in the geocode the address function as well.  It was a complete oversight on my part.  Completely stupid.  I've only been having a minute here and there to work on this recently, so I forgot what I was doing.  Needed a fresh set of eyes.  Thanks for your time.  :-)

Comment: Thanks.  I did learn a lot just from the couple of comments that everyone had.  It was really helpful.  :-)