# Google Maps - Marker click event not firing

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am clearly doing something wrong, but danged if I know what it is.  I have the following code where I put a map on a webpage, get the bounds, call back to my system and get locations within the system, and display markers on the map.  I would like to display some data when the marker is clicked on, however, I am not getting the click event of a marker to fire.  I am clearly missing something, but don't know what it is.  Any ideas are appreciated.  TIA.

```
    map.setZoom(12);
    var Latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    var Longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    map.setCenter({ lat: Latitude, lng: Longitude });
    var bounds = map.getBounds();
    var url = "/api/ReportingWeb/NearbyCleanliness";
    var lowerLeft = bounds.getSouthWest();
    var upperRight = bounds.getNorthEast();
    var lat0 = lowerLeft.lat();
    var lng0 = lowerLeft.lng();
    var lat1 = upperRight.lat();
    var lng1 = upperRight.lng();
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var data = { LowerLeftLat: lat0, LowerLeftLng: lng0, UpperRightLat: lat1, UpperRightLng: lng1 };
    $.get(url, data, function (result) {
        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            var address = result[i].Address1 + " " +
                (result[i].Address2 != null ? result[i].Address2 : "") +
                " " + result[i].City + " " + result[i].Province + " " +
                result[i].PostalCode + " " + result[i].Country;
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: geocodeAddress(geocoder, map, address),
                map: map,
                title: address,
                content: address
            });
            marker.addListener('click', function () {
                console.log("clicked");
                alert("hi");
            });
        }
    });
    function geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap, address) {
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
            if (status === 'OK') {
                resultsMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: resultsMap,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location
                });
            } else {
                alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: duplicate of [adding infowindow to google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47949144/adding-infowindow-to-google-maps)

Comment: For some reason, my marker's click event isn't firing.  I am not quite sure why and am looking for suggestions.

Comment: Did you read my comment on the original version of this question? It is still true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

geocodeAddress() is not returning a position, so your marker code is placed incorrectly.

The marker click listener should be set along with the marker-creation code inside geocodeAddress().

You were creating markers in inside geocodeAddress but setting the onclick outside of it, where they weren't working.

```
        map.setZoom(12);
        var Latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        var Longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        map.setCenter({ lat: Latitude, lng: Longitude });
        var bounds = map.getBounds();
        var url = "/api/ReportingWeb/NearbyCleanliness";
        var lowerLeft = bounds.getSouthWest();
        var upperRight = bounds.getNorthEast();
        var lat0 = lowerLeft.lat();
        var lng0 = lowerLeft.lng();
        var lat1 = upperRight.lat();
        var lng1 = upperRight.lng();
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var data = { LowerLeftLat: lat0, LowerLeftLng: lng0, UpperRightLat: lat1, UpperRightLng: lng1 };
        $.get(url, data, function (result) {
            for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                var address = result[i].Address1 + " " +
                    (result[i].Address2 != null ? result[i].Address2 : "") +
                    " " + result[i].City + " " + result[i].Province + " " +
                    result[i].PostalCode + " " + result[i].Country;
                //-------need not create markers here------------------
                geocodeAddress(geocoder, map, address);
            }
        });
        //-------place marker onclicks inside the function------------------
        function geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap, address) {
            geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
                if (status === 'OK') {
                    resultsMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: resultsMap,
                        position: results[0].geometry.location,
                        title: address,
                        content: address
                    });
                    marker.addListener('click', function () {
                        console.log("clicked");
                        alert("hi");
                    });
                } else {
                    alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Now, I get it.  Danged, this has been driving me crazy.  I see said the blind man.  Thanks!